# clickable area shifted when typesetting by xelatex for Clickable Plots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have the following codes for `clickable plots`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.clickable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} 
\pgfplotsset{yticklabel style={text width=2em,align=right}} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    axis line style={-},
] 
\addplot+[scatter,only marks,
samples=50,scatter src=y]
{x-x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When typesetting by `xelatex`, some texts like "+0.0pt+0.0pt" appear before and after the clickable area. However, it is OK for the result typesetted from `pdflatex` or `lualatex`. [image: typesetting by <code>xelatex</code>]

[image: typesetting by <code>pdflatex</code> or <code>lualatex</code>]

Comment: I run the 'TeXlive' 2015 and build the program with 'TeXworks' on Win 10.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I can reproduce the issue with an up-to-date MikTeX.

Comment: I'm inclined to consider it a bug in `edvipdfm.def`

Comment: I should typeset with 'XeLaTeX', because I have to deal with 'Chinese' with 'xeCJK'. How to resolve the bug in 'edvipdfm.def'? Thank you @egreg

Comment: @ChangyuWU It just required browsing a 72 MiB log file. `;-)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `acrotex` packages that are loaded by the `pgfplots.clickable` library forget to load the `calc` package, which is needed in `edvipdfm.def`, see, for example, line 25

```
\setlength{\@tempdima}{\eq@rectH+\ef@border@adj}%
```

You solve your issue by loading `calc` before `pgfplots`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.clickable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} 
\pgfplotsset{yticklabel style={text width=2em,align=right}}
```